# Calling a method from an owned object on the owner

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, composition

I have a table view class called `RootViewController` and a class providing WiFi functionality called `WifiClass`. When I load the `RootViewController` class, I am calling a method named `setup` on `WifiClass`, which will do the Wifi connection initialization.

While the app is running, if any connected device sends some data to my device, there is a stream handler delegate in the Wifi class which will trigger. At that time, I need to call a method named `myMethod` from my `RootViewController`. Please can anyone tell me a good way to do this properly?

Comment: To be sure, the wifi class instance acts as delegate to all web requests. Right? And where is this instance initialized?

Comment: all things in wifi connection class

Comment: just call the initialization method when my mainViewController is loading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a different conceptes in Objective-C like

- [Delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14-SW1)
- [Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Notification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH35-SW1)
- [Key-Value-Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the stream handler is a delegate **of** the WifiClass? In that case, set your RootViewController as the delegate of the WifiClass. In the delegate callback, implemented in RootViewController, call myMethod in RVC:

```
// RootViewController.m
- (void)delegateCallback {
    [self myMethod];
}
```

**Response to comments:**
In your WifiClass, you'll have to create an instance variable for the delegate.

```
@protocol WifiStreamDelegate
- (void)handleNewStream:(id)someStreamObject;
@end

@interface WifiClass : NSObject {
    // *delegate* is an object that conforms to the WifiStreamDelegate protocol
    id<WifiStreamDelegate> delegate;
    // …Other instance variables    
}
// You don't want to own your delegate
// Use the *assign* flag
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<WifiStreamDelegate> delegate;
// …Other properties

@end

@implementation WifiClass
@synthesize delegate;
// …Other methods
@end
```

Then in your RootViewController, you have to implement the delegate and hook things up:

```
#import "WifiClass.h"
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController<WifiStreamDelegate>
{
    WifiClass *wifi;
    // …Other instance variables
}
// *wifi* is now an object you own—retain it
@property (nonatomic, retain) WifiClass *wifi
// …Other properties
@end

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize wifi;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (!(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
        return nil;
    if (!self.wifi)
        wifi = [[WifiClass alloc] init];
    // Set delegate
    wifi.delegate = self;
}

- (void)myMethod {
    // Do something
}

// Delegate method
- (void)handleNewStream:(id)someStreamObject {
    // Handle stream
    [self myMethod];
}
@end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: what are the changes that i need to do in Wifi class?

Comment: i think Objective-C does not support class variables as C++ does.

Comment: That's not class variable; it's an instance variable of type `WifiClass` with a name of `wifi`.

Obj-C has basic support for class variables. You just have to declare them as `static` and outside any enclosing code block.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the `welcomemessage` method to the `appDelegate`. This would make more sense as I assume the "message" does not need to be associated with any particular view Controller.

So when your `wifi delegate` is triggered just reference the `appDelegate` and call the method:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] welcomeMessage];
```

Comment: sorry..i need to trigger a method from my viewcontroller or table View controller classs

Comment: but that wasn't what you asked. Anyway MVC will still work, in that the appdelegate responding methid can notify the method in the viewcontroller. See answer answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(yourMethod) to:nil from:self forEvent:someEvent];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do. One is to have a weak reference to the object whose method you want to invoke. In this case the view controller is the object. Declare an `assign`-able property of the `MainViewController` (assuming this is the class) in the wifi class and set it to the view controller during initialization. Since you've a reference to the view controller, you can invoke the method you want in the delegate method.

Another approach is to use `Blocks`. The block's definition can be -

```
typedef void (^UpdateHandler)(void);

...

@interface WiFiConnection:NSObject <...> {
    ...
    UpdateHandler updateHandler;
}
...
- (void)setUpdateHandler:(UpdateHandler)handler;
@end

@implemention WiFiConnection
...
- (void)setUpdateHandler:(UpdateHandler)handler {
    updateHandler = handler;
}
...
- (void)delegateMethodFromWhichYouWantToInvoke {
    ...
    if ( updateHandler != NULL ) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), updateHandler);
    }
}
...
@end
```

You can now pass the update block during initialization,

```
WiFiConnection *connection = [[WiFiConnection alloc] init];
...
__block MainViewController *controller = self;
[connection setUpdateHandler:^{
    [controller welcomeMessage];
}];
```

There is probably a lot in there. Let me know if it is still unclear. Read up on GCD. It is a very powerful tool in my opinion.

Comment: what is rootViewController .is it my mainViewController

Comment: It is a `block`. In short, it is a piece of code that you can pass as objects. Similar looking to function pointers but not exactly. You can define a block within a method but not a function. In this case `^{ [controller welcomeMessage]; }` is a block that we've written on the go. Block type is a combination of arguments that can be passed and what is returned. We defined a short hand for it by using `typedef` in case of `UpdateHandler`. This block type takes no arguments and returns a void.

Comment: This is a lengthy topic to cover and probably best if I pass you some links. Take a look at [this](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/) and [this](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html) to get started.

Comment: However if you do not have time to spend on learning them, you can go with the first approach. Set the weak reference to the controller instance when creating the wifi connection object.

Answer (score 0):

just send an notification......

post it like this...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MyMethodNotification" object:self];
```

receive it like this...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MyMethod:) name:@"MyMethodNotification" object:nil];
```

your method....

- (void)MyMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ur code
  }

remove it

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Honestly, a delegate was designed for this type of situation. A notification results in unnecessary complication, overhead, and IMO here reduces encapsulation.